# How to save animation generated in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: manipulate, front-end, animation, jupyter-notebook

I'm playing with the [Free Wolfram Engine for Developers](https://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2019/05/launching-today-free-wolfram-engine-for-developers/) together with [Wolfram Language kernel for Jupyter notebooks](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter). To my surprise, `Manipulate`/`Animate` still works to some degree:

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[x+y//Sin,{x,-3,3},{y,-3+a,3+a}],{{a,0,"a"},-Pi,Pi}]
```

[image]

But how to save this animation? The usual "right click and save as" strategy doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried `Export`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 That does work, but I'm wondering if there's a more straightforward way. (Since the "save picture as" pops up when the animation is right clicked, I guess there may be a GIF/SWF somewhere. )

Comment: The "right click" calls up a `ContextMenu`, which is handled by the Front End. Maybe that can be or has been implemented in Jupyter.

Comment: You can also export `Manipulate[..]` as a notebook and open it with the `wolframplayer` that gets installed together with the Wolfram Engine